# $myClass->IdentifierIDs = String::ListIntegers($pv->IDs, ',', ',', 1);

Tags: php

what does $myClass->IdentifierIDs = String::ListIntegers($pv->IDs, ',', ',', 1);    do.
i never seen string::

Comment: google php :: - your answer is on the first page

Comment: One could even use: "http://www.php.net/::", you'd be amazed how many things can be found just by adding it as the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is a custom class with a static function ListIntegers. You should look in the includes to see if such a class or namespace is included or [autoloaded](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).